# Socket.io WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket

So i have today changed my connection to both my API and my socket so that they run through a proxy.

The node api works fine however im having some problems with my socket.io.

Everything from chat - upload works fine and the user can't feel any difference however in the console i get the following error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://client.example.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=e31aZ7dQdUI-nxvTAAAN' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

Can anyone tell me what this is? is it dangerous as i said everything seem to be working fine however i don't feel comforatable pushing this error to my live enviroment before knowing exactly what it is?

Comment: This sounds like your proxy perhaps does not understand the "upgrade" header that a webSocket connection uses.  You need to make sure you're using a proxy that specifically has webSocket support.  It may still be working because socket.io will "fall-back" to polling if webSocket is not supported, but that is not nearly as efficient as actually using a webSocket.

Comment: @jfriend00 How do i add an  upgrade header?

Comment: You don't add an upgrade header.  It's already on the original request.  Please read my comment again.  This sounds like an issue with your proxy not supporting webSocket requests.